# Reading a string using bne

Tags: assembly, mips

Suppose we have a string of ASCII characters stored in memory. The string's length is in `$a0` and the address of the string is in `$a1`.

I know we can get this string using load instruction but is there any way to get the string  using "only"  `bne`?

( Which means the only instruction that can be used on the part of memory that contains this string is `bne`. )

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways you would use `bne` on a string.

First, since you know the length, you might have a loop where you decrement $a0 until `bne $a0 $zero getChar` falls through instead of looping.

Second, *if* you're talking about an ASCIIZ string, you could read characters until you reach the `\0` at the end. That would be something like `bne $t0 $zero getChar` where $t0 contains the character just read from memory (by something like `lb $t0 0($a1)`).

The second one seems less likely because they're giving you the string length. My guess is that the exercise is intended to show you how to loop until a variable reaches zero.

Comment: but fot the getChar parts i'll still need to use lb, right?
Is there anyway to not use lb at all?

Comment: Ya. You can't access the memory without using a load instruction of some type